# Magento2 - Add multiple shipping methods to cities within a specific country?

Tags: magento2, shipping, multiple, add

In `Magento2`, I see that it lacks flexibility in shipping options so much, because in a different country from America, I don't know specifically which method of shipping Opencart has great flexibility in adding countries and cities and pricing them with shipping at the asking price.

Here in my country 28 provinces or cities for each city at a different freight rate than the other, I am tired of research and many experiences without any benefit, I would like to add multiple shipping methods for each city on the payment page please?

I want a solution, thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Default magento 2 allow to set multi shipping address for each items in one order.

Step 1: you need go to config to Allow Shipping to Multiple Addresses.
Magento admin > Store -> configuration -> Sales -> multishipping setting -> Allow Shipping to Multiple Addresses -> YES.

Step 2: add two items or more than 2 qty in order.

Step 3: In mini cart click "View and Edit Cart" then in "Summary" click "Check Out with Multiple Addresses" you will see the page allow setting shipping to multi address(attached image) [image]
Good luck!